# Only In Pagination page count Query: (PDO Query Error) -> server has gone away in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination, server

Please give me little help, I found in google and stackoverFlow but cant find solution.

In my website has 80,000 rows, and daily 1000 rows increase,

My web all Queries work properly, but some time pagination query return error, (after 30-60 sec)

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in  
/home/name/public_html/example.com/classes/functions.php on line 226
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header in 
/home/name/public_html/example.com/classes/functions.php on line 226
```

I am using simple count Query, I use pagination with different condition, and if return rows is more than 8000, only that query ERROR show but some time,,

Here is a simple one query Example

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(groupName)) FROM  `table` WHERE `type` = 'string'";
//return expect 24,000 count
```

Now please Any Expert give me solution.

I test one thing to check server response,

I test , and get table 20,000 rows with `WHERE CLAUSE` and server return 20,000 rows from same table where pagination query run, but What the problem with my pagination Query? Why its return SERVER GONE AWAY Error

Please Dont suggest me to Increase server time out limit, I want to load my website with in 2 sec, not with in 2 min.

Table structure

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Can you provide table structure/indexes etc?

Comment: Table structure snapshot http://prntscr.com/560mqg

Comment: If i fetch data 20,000 rows (7 columns), its working ok, but if i run query to count rows,return expect => 8000, Error return (but some time): server has gone away.

Comment: This is not a table structure. Table structure shows column types and indexes.

Comment: Opps Sorry, Here is table structure, http://prntscr.com/56101b ,,, No index column, no relation. only primary key column – -- --  After your Question about Table structure, i update table datatype.. Please review this snapshot http://prntscr.com/56137d

Comment: Ok i don't see index on mov_grp_name. You use this field to count by right? Try to put index on that column.

Comment: Thank you.. I put index on mov_name and mov_grp_name ,, now my web performance is improve :)

Answer (score 0):

According table structure it seems you need index on the columns you use to count by (mov_grp_name, mov_name).